# Should I install a module globally as long as at least two apps are using it?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a GoDaddy server to myself. I intend to run several node.js web applications in it.

Does it make sense to install every module globally as long as there is a chance that at least two applications may be using it?

What are the advantages of installing a module local to a project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different applications might begin to use different module versions as the time progresses and depending on how often you are able to update them. Some versions might have breaking changes as well so you won't be able to use the same module in two different projects because a particular module version might be working fine in one project but the API might have changed for another project. So its not a good idea. You will have a lot more freedom if each project has its own set of modules.